# Duplicate rows of data output with joined tables and user id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently building an event management system using PHP and MySQL. I use sessions to manage the user who is logged in, and currently have three tables; users, events and notes.

The idea is that each event has its details (anyone can add events and edit them) and each user then has personal notes that only they see on the 'Event's List' page.

I have personal notes working for each user, however, if another user has entered notes for that event I get a duplicate output of the event (duplicates a number of times, depending on how many other users notes there are). I know the way I'm doing it is possibly incorrect or not standardised, but any help in getting me there would be appreciated.

Here is the MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
        id, 
        events.event_name, 
        events.event_date, 
        events.event_time,
        events.event_location,
        events.event_price,
        events.event_description,
        events.event_tickets,
        events.event_shared_notes,
        notes.event_id,
        notes.user_id,
        notes.notes_text
    FROM events LEFT JOIN notes ON events.id = notes.event_id
    WHERE DATEDIFF(event_date,NOW()) >= 0
    ORDER BY event_date ASC, event_time ASC;
```

Here is a snippet of the code used to put it into a table:

```
<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?> 
        <tr> 
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td> <!-- htmlentities is not needed here because $row['id'] is always an integer --> 
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['event_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['event_date'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['event_time'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['event_location'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
            <td> <!-- Your notes -->
                <?php 
                    //Checks for comments by the current user (ID) 
                    if ($row['user_id'] == $get_current_user_id) {
                        echo htmlentities($row['notes_text'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                    }
                    else { //no notes, empty display
                    } ?>
            </td> 
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

And finally an example of how it looks output:
[image: duplicate rows]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you try picturing what your ideal result set looks like, you'll see that there must be duplicate rows from the `events` table, since it has a one-to-many relationship with `notes`. The only options I see are:

1. Run an aggregate function on the rows from `notes` (e.g., `COUNT`, `SUM`), grouping by event ID, instead of returning each row. This doesn't seem applicable in your case.
2. Leave your query as-is, and make your client code aware of when the event ID changes as you iterate through the result set.
3. Do the joining logic in your code. So you would first run a single query against `events`, and then for each result, run another query against `notes` to find notes with a matching event ID.

Comment: I know this is a really old post, but I'm very interested in finding more resources about option #3. I'm trying to create a list of master records that link out to several many to one tables, and even one table that links to another, then to a many to one table. I'd rather join these in PHP then output some super joined table mess with zillions of duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

These duplicated rows are other user's notes to this event - you only skip to display them. Filter directly in query with (sth equivalent for) `WHERE ... AND notes.user_id = {$get_current_user_id}`
No need to compare (nor select) user_id in loop then. On the other hand if notes_text is NULL when no comment by this user was added (hence `LEFT JOIN` I persume) you will need to replace it with empty string.